# Error: "Duplicate files during packaging of APK"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

We are trying to migrate our project to other architecture.

We are met with the following error message:

> Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK >/Users/xavi/Programming/wdandroid/project/build/outputs/apk/project-debug-unaligned.apk

Path in archive: lib/armeabi/libshinobicharts-android.so

> Origin 1: >/Users/xavi/Programming/wdandroid/project/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/wdandroid/shinobichartsandroidlibrary/unspecified/jni/armeabi/libshinobicharts-android.so
>
> Origin 2: >/Users/xavi/Programming/wdandroid/project/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libshinobicharts-android.so

You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:

```
android {

 packagingOptions {

   exclude ‘lib/armeabi/libshinobicharts-android.so’

 }

}
```

> Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi/libshinobicharts-android.so
>
> File 1: >/Users/xavi/Programming/wdandroid/project/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/wdandroid/shinobichartsandroidlibrary/unspecified/jni/armeabi/libshinobicharts-android.so
>
> File 2: >/Users/xavi/Programming/wdandroid/project/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/wdandroid/shinobichartsandroidlibrary/unspecified/jni/armeabi/libshinobicharts-android.so
>
> Information:BUILD FAILED

I tried some solutions but It dosen`t work:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'lib/armeabi/libshinobicharts-android.so'
}
```

Trying to exclude the package as suggested (even though that seems like a bad idea) doesn’t resolve the error message.

We’ve been debugging this afternoon but can’t seem to make any progress. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your `dependencies` section from `build.gradle` file? Also, you have the `.so`, `.jar` or `.zip` file to your `lib` folder, correct? Please show the structure of the `lib` folder

Comment: It's everythink ok. I will put the code later , the problem I think is the duplicate lib :/

Comment: I solved the problem using pickFirst. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Who is Adam? Likely you're building the native assembly from source and also adding it as `libshinobicharts-android.so`. Simply delete that file and the assembly should still be linked.

Comment: I will try it this afternoon. Adam is an architure for mobiles . Thank you .

Comment: @XaviJimenez honestly never heard of it - and the NDK does not know it either.

Comment: I think that the problem is a duplicate lib.

Comment: Still not working :/ I need this libs

Answer (score 1):

**There are some problem New versions of the android studio:
Try these steps:**

1. You have to build a new project(no alternate  is available)
2. Copy and paste your code from the previous project to new projects!
3. Just try to build .apk after pasting some code  So, You confirm that there is no error!

*for the future just make some copies of your project  like when 5% completed,10% completed, etc*

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved this using pickFirst very useful

Comment: pickfirst if you have 2 libraries that do the same pickfirst take this one and ignore the others it really helped me

Comment: Well done Bro It was a logical error made by you ,Sir.